# Find out backend used in company completion

Tags: company-mode

When using custom `company` backends, `company-complete` ends up returning no completions due to a misbehaving backend. In such cases, it would be helpful to know out which company backend was used to generate the list of completions. How do I get this information after a `company-complete` invocation?

Comment: The currently used backend should be displayed in the modeline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`company` has a very useful feature that modifies its modeline lighter to display the backend currently in use.

Comment: What is that feature and how do I enable it?

Comment: Exactly what I wrote in the answer: The currently used backend is displayed in the modeline. It's unconditionally enabled.

Comment: I am not seeing it. That probably means Moritz answer applies to me or I have disabled it and forgotten about it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Nor am I seeing it.  I simply see `company` in the modeline. @Dmitry's answer does work here.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to start with a minimal Emacs session (`emacs -Q` followed by `M-x package-initialize` and evaluating your company config) to exclude any interference of your init file.

Answer (score 25):

You can type <kbd>M-x company-diag</kbd> now, and see the used backend in the resulting buffer.

Answer (score 1):

If the first answer does not work:

Using the package [elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy), hides the company lighter in the modeline (even in other major modes). Same might be true for globally installed major modes.